# AS3 working with lots of text inputs?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to setup a Flash piece that has a bunch of user input fields, and several dynamic text fields that update based on what gets input.

What is the most efficient type of listener to use that will get triggered after any input field gets tabbed, or clicked away from?

I don't want to have to set up a focus_out for everyone of my input fields.  I just want one function to tell all my variables to update any time an input gets changed...

Not sure if this helps or complicates things, but most all of my inputs/dynamics are nested inside an MC.  Each MC has a subject field, and 7 other inputs, and 6 dynamic variables.  Then I want to be able to duplicate that whole shebang multiple times...

Thanks for any suggestions.  Especially typed out code suggestions as I am more or less an AS3 noob.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read **[How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. The point of this site is when you have a task & that gives you a problem, so you show what you've tried to do & also what you suspect is the problem code and then volunteers try to help you to fix it.

Comment: It's not so much you want one **function** but more like you want one **class**. The class would be code in an **.as** (class file) and you import that into your project. The code would create a MovieClip object and add a subject textfield + your other input/dynamic textfields as **public** variables. Let's say you call it "**textsClass**". Now you import that class in your main project's code and to "clone" multiple times you instantiate multiple times (ie: `var mytext1 : textsClass = new textsClass` and do same for `var mytext2` etc just make a `something = new textsClass`)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have a function, let's say `updateFields`, which can be called when the user either clicks away or tabs to another field.  Fine. But because mouse events and keyboard events are different type events, you'll actually need three functions to get this up and running.  The first two will handle the event listening portion, and will then call the `updateFields` function.

```
private function mouseClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   updateFields();
}

private function tabPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   updateFields();
}

private function updateFields():void
{
    // code that updates the fields
    // hopefully you have some?
}
```

Hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.